# How to force a user to enter the data in DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a dataGrid. When the first cell (which is a template column containing a textbox) of any row is focused and if user does not enter any text and tries to move to another cell or any control outside the datagrid, he should be forced to enter data in that cell before losing focus. If he does not want to enter any data in that cell, then he should press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  or  <kbd>Esc</kbd>  as per his choice. Can anybody help me to achieve this behavior?

Comment: If you are allowing user to leave `textbox` empty after pressing `enter` or `esc`. Why do you want to force user to press one of those keys?

Comment: @Shaharyar When user presses Esc, I will close the Window. If he presses Enter and first cell is empty then I will delete the row. I dont like this facility but client wants it so I am trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to achieve this:

**First:**

You can use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and set the template to a `Textbox`. This textbox has a `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` event you can use. Setting `Handled` to true prevents the `Textbox` from losing focus.

Example:

```
 <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="header">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding DisplayedName}" PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Second**

You can also add a `Style` to the `DataGrid`. This style sets the `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` event of all cells:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" Handler="OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

In the event handler you check if the cell is in the correct column and then set `Handled` to true:

```
public void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as DataGridCell).Column.Header.ToString() == "The column I'm looking for")
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```